# Is it possible to add an interval in browser console that keeps running after reloading?

Tags: javascript, browser, console

I am wondering if it is possible to add an interval from the browser console in a given website, where given interval keeps running even after reloading the website.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijRZW.png)

Comment: No I think it's not possible from the console, since everything is refreshed and it's just like opening a new page. If you want a script to run on a particular website, you can use add-ons like Tampermonkey.

Comment: Is it possible to execute a script (or a js block code) from another page that gets executed in the page i want?